# $n$-th term of a sequence from generating function $\frac{1}{(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^7)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, generating-functions

I have a generating function of a sequence such that

$$\frac{1}{(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^7)}.$$

They are the product of three geometric series with coefficient 1.
Now I want to transform this into infinite sum form so that I can get nth term explicitly. However, I can not refactor denominator to get power of $(1-x)$ or partial fractions. Is there any identity I must know or is this completely wrong way of solving?

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A008671](https://oeis.org/A008671).

Comment: You can use this formula:
$$[x^n] \, \frac 1 {(1 - x^2) (1 - x^3) (1 - x^7)} =
\frac 1 {504} (6 n (n + 2) + 185 + 63 (-1)^n) + \\
  \frac 1 9 \cases {2 & $n \bmod 3 = 0$ \\ -1 & otherwise} +
 \frac 1 7 \cases {
  2 & $n \bmod 7 = 0 \lor n \bmod 7 = 2$ \\
  -2 & $n \bmod 7 = 1$ \\
  -1 & $n \bmod 7 = 4 \lor n \bmod 7 = 5$ \\
  0 & otherwise}.$$

Comment: You can write it as $$\left(\frac{1-x^{42}}{1-x^{2\,}}\right) \left(\frac{1-x^{42}}{1-x^{3\,}}\right) \left(\frac{1-x^{42}}{1-x^{7\,}}\right) \frac{1}{(1-x^{42})^3}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Using runway44's suggestion:

$$x^2=u$$

$$\frac{1-u^{21}}{1-u}=\sum_{k=0}^{20} u^k$$

$$x^3=v$$

$$\frac{1-v^{14}}{1-v}=\sum_{l=0}^{13} v^l$$

$$x^7=w$$

$$\frac{1-w^{6}}{1-w}=\sum_{m=0}^{5} w^m $$

$$x^{42}=z$$

$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^3} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1) z^{n-2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(n+2) z^n$$

Which means:

$$\frac{1}{(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^7)}= \\ =\left(\sum_{k=0}^{20} x^{2k} \right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^{13} x^{3l} \right) \left(\sum_{m=0}^{5} x^{7m} \right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(n+2) x^{42n}$$

Which allows us, after some tedious algebra, to find the general expression for the terms, which Maxim already provided in another comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use partial fractions, and pry out the coefficients of interest:

$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(1 - x^2) (1 - x^3) (1 - x^7)}
  &= \frac{x^4 + 2 x^3 + 2 x^2 + 2}
          {7 (x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)}
        + \frac{x + 2}{9 (x^2 + x + 1)}
        + \frac{1}{8 (x + 1)}
        - \frac{17}{72 (x - 1)}
        + \frac{3}{28 (x - 1)^2}
        - \frac{1}{42 (x - 1)^3} \\
  &= \frac{(x^4 + 2 x^3 + 2 x^2 + 2)(1 - x)}
          {7 (1 - x^7)}
        + \frac{(x + 2) (1 - x)}{9 (1 - x^3)}
        + \frac{1}{8 (x + 1)}
        - \frac{17}{72 (x - 1)}
        + \frac{3}{28 (x - 1)^2}
        - \frac{1}{42 (x - 1)^3}
\end{align*}$

Multiply out the numerators, and you are left with picking off the coefficients of powers of $x$ in geometric series and series of the form:

$\begin{align*}
(1 - x)^m
  &= \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \binom{-m}{k} x^k \\
  &= \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{k + m - 1}{m - 1} x^k
\end{align*}$